# How do I create multiple connections to my server

Tags: java, sockets

I created a java server using the socket method, but I could make it connect to 1 client at a time.

My question is how do I make my server to connect to each client separately and communicate with each client equally so you know like 4 clients could use the app without being affected by other users but they could still use the server's service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Threads`, so each `Thread` can create a new connection with a client X like this :

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        CreateConnectionToYourClient();
    }
};
thread.start();
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: yes @EldarAzulay, they work, i use this technique for a multiple chat room

Comment: i'm sure it will work haha, because i already work with it :)

Comment: I have another question regarding that, in my server, after a client made the connection I made a theoretical infinite loop until the client disconnects, so where do I set the ending of the thread?

Comment: **unti the client disconnects** in this moment

Comment: it tells me to use final variables

Comment: this is another problem, can you post what you try to do?

Comment: Well, this code is designed for 1 client to log in and then send messages (ignore the meme variable names, I made this app and server for an inside meme): http://pastebin.com/CtzvSMRE (the code is too long I guess for this comment)

Comment: i don't get you @EldarAzulay, what did you mean?

Comment: here is the code I couldn't send it here in the comment: http://pastebin.com/CtzvSMRE (variables are pretty meme but ignore that)

Comment: you code is so long @EldarAzulay you can debug your program and find the part which make problem

Answer (score 0):

Make a Client object that holds the informatiom about the client (name, socket, additional infos required by your program), inside the main loop's class create an arraylist of clients.

When a new client joins, create a new client object and put him inside the arraylist. Loop through each client and update them if needed. You'll also need to check if they disconnected or not and remove them if they are. Because of this I advise you to loop through the clients from the last to the first, because then removing am object doesn't make another one get missed.

The object things is not necessary if you don't need to have additional info, just the socket, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: I don't understand that, a loop means that the program has to go 1 by 1 in the array and work against 1 client at a time. I want to make the clients work in parallel so they can use the server or even send messages to each other

Comment: @Eldar You should've mentioned that. That' also very simple. When they send  a message, check to which user it goes to, get that user from the arraylist (or hashmap if you like) and simply send it to him. As long as getting the sent data doesn't block the server, it'll be fine.